# Jquery UI datepicker calendar overriding A link class for a specific day?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

From lots of searching, I'm guessing there are a few options available, however I am trying to stick with Jquery UI datepicker out of the box if possible.

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

So as shown above, my code changes the style (i.e. return[true, myClass] on the first select of a day (image 1) and then when a second day is selected (range) as shown in image 2, the first day selected is overwritten.. however you can just see the background image peeping through (image 2).  Obviously the return [true, myClass] sets the TD class from what I can see, although the A element gets a class applied.

Unfortunately I have tried overriding the JQUI classes, for instance:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-state-active, .ui-state-default {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Sort of works for the current day, but not one that has already been selected.

Ideally I want to drop the css for that A tag/element on that specific day.  I already have the logic to display the desired class on first/second selection (which is adding/return [true, myClass] to show the green slash images) in the beforeShowDay function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cna you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi aka Edward, actually managed to solve the issue - actually a rather simple change and a subtle mis-understanding - I am going to post the solution (well my humble attempt!) this evening just for completeness.  Thanks for responding though!